# What is the Big Oh notation for a recursive function with one child call of n/2?

Tags: algorithm, recursion, time-complexity, big-o

```
public static int div(int numItems)
{
    if (numItems == 0)
        return 0;
    else
        return numItems%2 + div(numItems/2);
}
```

I am thinking that the time complexity will be logarithmic, i.e O(log n), but I am not able to figure out how. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: `T(n) = T(n/2) + 1` => `T(n) = Theta(log(n))`.

Comment: It should be T(n) =T(n/2)+3 right because one operation is for comparision, one is for addition and one is for modulus?

Comment: 1, 3, doesn't matter, either way it's `T(n/2) + constant`.  Bear in mind that not all operations cost the same.

Answer (score 1):

The complexity is O(logn). Imagine the number in its binary representation. Then the integer division by 2 is equivalent to removing the least significant bit from that representation. When all bits have been consumed the base case kicks in. As a number has O(logn) bits in its binary representation, this is also the complexity for this recursive function.